# Capitalise words for the Range in Google sheets

Tags: javascript

Can you please help me out with the code for JavaScript. I want to make sure that the range is automatically converted to it's Proper form (capitalised). I tried doing the following but it doesn't seem to work.
Thank you in advance.

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A5");
    range.value = range.value.toProperCase();
       String.prototype.toProperCase= function()
{
    return range.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + range.substring(1,range.length).toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: return range.toUpperCase();

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the function before calling it. Also you don't need to use `range.length` in the second `substr`, it will automatically take the string till its end:

```
String.prototype.toProperCase= function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A5");
range.value = range.value.toProperCase();
```

Comment: It is not working unfortunately, I have tried rearranging the code as follows

Comment: function String.prototype.toProperCase()
{
    return range.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + range.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A5");
range.value = range.value.toProperCase();